# Formatting block of text in Notepad++ with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I can't get this to work, so I'm asking you for help.

```
(432, 412), (673, 187), (231, 548)
```

I'm trying to automate a large file with data like this format to;

```
432, 412
673, 187
231, 548
```

In Notepad++, I am trying the extended search mode with `)`, `\s` - but it doesn't find anything using that search string.

Comment: But you have tried something, haven't you? Please share at least one attempt.

Comment: I'm in Notepad++ trying the extended search mode with ), \s - but it doesn't find anything using that search string.

Answer (score 4):

With *Regular expression* radio button selected, use

```
\((\d+,\s*\d+)\),?\s*
```

Replace with `$1\r\n` (the `$1` is a backreference to the only number capture group defined in the regex pattern that captures digits, `,`, space(s)?, and digits again).

The regex will match:

- `\(` - opening `(`
- `(\d+,\s*\d+)` - Group 1 matching 1 or more digits, a `,`, zero or more whitespaces (`\s*`), one or more digits
- `\)` - a closing `)`
- `,?` - an optional comma (1 or 0 occurrences)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

[image]

Comment: Beat me by two seconds.. :-)

Comment: It's OK but `$2` is superfluous in the replacement part.

Comment: :) That is a remnant from my previous replacement attempt. Thanks, Toto.

Answer (score 1):

To match parentheses with regex, you must escape them with a slash.

You could use two regex steps to achieve what you need.

1) find

```
\),
```

and replace with

```
\n
```

2) find

```
\(
```

and replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In cntl+F , select extended (\n,\r,..), then find '),'. add space if you have space in between each pair, replace with \r\n, do replace all. Then find (, replace with empty string. Then find ')' replace with empty string.